# getting data from xml to java

Tags: java, php, android, xml

How could I get the data from a xml, which is generated with php, in java.
I need the data to display it in a listview in my android app.

The phpcode take the data form the mysqlquery and fetch the array in the variabel xml and put it over echo out. The data for the mysqlquery are from the android app over POST.

phpcode:

```
//MySQL zugangsdaten
$server = "server";
$datenbank = "database";
$username = "username";
$passwort = "password";

//Verbindung zur MySqldatenbank herstellen
$link = mysql_connect($server, $username, $passwort);
if (!$link) die(mysql_error());

//Datenbank auswählen
$db = mysql_select_db($datenbank, $link);
//<---- End Login ---->

$_linie = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["linie"]), ENT_COMPAT);
$_richtung = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["richtung"]), ENT_COMPAT);

$sql_befehl = "SELECT * From Kontrolleure where linie = '$_linie' AND richtung = '$_richtung'";
$query = mysql_query($sql_befehl, $link);
if(mysql_error())
            {
                die(mysql_error());
            }

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {   
            $count = $count + 1;
            $xml = $xml."<Konduktor>";
            $xml = $xml."<id>".$result['id']."</id>";
            $xml = $xml."<linie>".$result['linie']."</linie>";
            $xml = $xml."<endstation>".$result['richtung']."</endstation>";
            $xml = $xml."<station>".$result['station']."</station>";
            $xml = $xml."<zeit>".$result['zeit']."</zeit>";
            $xml = $xml."</Konduktor>";
        }
echo "<Konduktors count=\"$count\">";
echo $xml;
echo "</Konduktors>";
```

the xml response looks like this:

```
<Konduktors count="3">
   <Konduktor>
      <id>29</id>
      <linie>S23</linie>
      <endstation>Langenthal</endstation>
      <station>Brugg AG</station>
      <zeit>17:36:34</zeit>
   </Konduktor>
   <Konduktor>
      <id>30</id>
      <linie>S23</linie>
      <endstation>Langenthal</endstation>
      <station>Lupfig</station>
      <zeit>17:37:12</zeit>
   </Konduktor>
   <Konduktor>
      <id>32</id>
      <linie>S23</linie>
      <endstation>Langenthal</endstation>
      <station>Birr</station>
      <zeit>16:23:30</zeit>
    </Konduktor>
</Konduktors>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use an XML-Parser as illustrated in a load of tutorials [all over the Internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20parse%20xml).

Comment: You can use [XPath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAXB would handle that easily:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JaxbExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        String xml =
                "<Konduktors count=\"3\">\n" +
                "   <Konduktor>\n" +
                "      <id>29</id>\n" +
                "      <linie>S23</linie>\n" +
                "      <endstation>Langenthal</endstation>\n" +
                "      <station>Brugg AG</station>\n" +
                "      <zeit>17:36:34</zeit>\n" +
                "   </Konduktor>\n" +
                "   <Konduktor>\n" +
                "      <id>30</id>\n" +
                "      <linie>S23</linie>\n" +
                "      <endstation>Langenthal</endstation>\n" +
                "      <station>Lupfig</station>\n" +
                "      <zeit>17:37:12</zeit>\n" +
                "   </Konduktor>\n" +
                "   <Konduktor>\n" +
                "      <id>32</id>\n" +
                "      <linie>S23</linie>\n" +
                "      <endstation>Langenthal</endstation>\n" +
                "      <station>Birr</station>\n" +
                "      <zeit>16:23:30</zeit>\n" +
                "    </Konduktor>\n" +
                "</Konduktors>";
        Object object = JAXBContext.newInstance(Konduktors.class).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
        System.out.println(object);
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "Konduktors")
    static class Konduktors {
        private List<Konductor> konductors = new ArrayList<Konductor>();

        @XmlElement(name = "Konduktor")
        public List<Konductor> getKonductors() {
            return konductors;
        }

        public void setKonductors(List<Konductor> konductors) {
            this.konductors = konductors;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Konductors{" +
                    "konductors=" + konductors +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    static class Konductor {
        private int id;
        private String linie;
        private String endstation;
        private String zeit;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getLinie() {
            return linie;
        }

        public void setLinie(String linie) {
            this.linie = linie;
        }

        public String getEndstation() {
            return endstation;
        }

        public void setEndstation(String endstation) {
            this.endstation = endstation;
        }

        public String getZeit() {
            return zeit;
        }

        public void setZeit(String zeit) {
            this.zeit = zeit;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Konductor{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", linie='" + linie + '\'' +
                    ", endstation='" + endstation + '\'' +
                    ", zeit='" + zeit + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Other options include [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) or [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/conGettingStartedwithXMLBeans.html) for higher-level abstractions and [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) or [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) for lower-level ones--you have to do more work with these but have a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Two points: JAXB does not run on Android and Simple XML is the best framwork for this job on Android IMO.

Answer (score 2):

There are xml parsing tools for this kind of thing. At my work we use XMLBeans:
http://xmlbeans.apache.org/

I found using it to be fairly straightforward, and am kind of a rank amateur at this kind of stuff.